# How do I install the 2013 SharePoint PowerShell module on my Windows 7 client computer?

Tags: 2013, powershell

I just installed SharePoint 2013 Foundation on a server. I'm confused as to how I can access the [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) cmdlets from my client pc. Everything I read assumes you're in front of the actual server. Is there anything like an RSAT module I can install on my client PC?

I don't want to use psremoting, because that has some limitations (I have a lot of custom modules loaded on my client pc). Is there really nothing like say the [AD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory), [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System), [DHCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol), etc. PowerShell modules, but for SharePoint?

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434304/how-to-work-with-sharepoint-cmdlet-without-installing-sharepoint but can't flag it as such when it is on a different Stack site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to be either on the sharepoint server, or use the PSSession module (PSRemote)

```
New-PSSession -ComputerName SP2013Server
```

Then add:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell
```

Comment: Booo is that really the only way? They have a management shell for Sharepoint Online which looks like what I want, but this is an in house installation (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161362(v=office.15).aspx). I'm surprised they have this for the cloud offering, but not in house- or maybe I'm not misunderstanding something?

Comment: Nope, that's the way it is. Probably for security reasons, but I agree the parts available in the Online shell could be available for client in on prem as well

Comment: @user1028270 you could just add it to your profile.ps1 and you wouldn't have to remember the command

Answer (score 18):

Instead of using PowerShell Remoting with SharePoint you could consider another approach.

Since SharePoint 2013 supports [several sets of APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164060%28v=office.15%29.aspx), you could *utilize client APIs (CSOM/REST) in PowerShell*.

As you already mentioned Microsoft released [Windows PowerShell for SharePoint Online](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161362%28v=office.15%29.aspx) for working with SharePoint Online. This SDK uses CSOM as the underlying API for SharePoint Online cmdlets.

*To summarize, instead of using PowerShell based on Server Side Object Model (SSOM), it is proposed to perform an operations using client APIs (CSOM/REST) in PowerShell*

### Example

[Get-SPFeature](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607945%28v=office.15%29.aspx) cmdlet returns the SharePoint Features, for example:

```
Get-SPFeature -Limit ALL | Where-Object {$_.Scope -eq "SITE"}
```

The CSOM version:

```
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url)
$siteFeatures = $context.Site.Features 
$context.Load($siteFeatures) 
$context.ExecuteQuery()
```

The REST version:

```
$Url = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/site/features"
$data = Invoke-RestSPO $Url Get $UserName $Password
```

`Invoke-RestSPO` is a custom cmdlet, follow [this post](http://blog.vgrem.com/2014/04/15/consuming-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-from-powershell/?s=powershell#) for a details.

### References

- [Choose the right API set in SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164060%28v=office.15%29.aspx)
- [Consuming the SharePoint 2013 REST API from PowerShell](http://blog.vgrem.com/2014/04/15/consuming-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-from-powershell/)

Comment: Nice alternative approach!

Comment: Both of these seem to require `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll`. Which I'm not sure if is up-to-date.

Comment: @Nae, yep, it has a dependency to SharePoint Client SDK which could be downloaded [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038)

Comment: @VadimGremyachev Thanks for the reply, can you also verify that this is compatible with Office365's Sharepoint?

Comment: @Nae, i confirm it, the provided link for SDK which targets Office365/SharePoint Online

Comment: @VadimGremyachev I keep getting error: `Add-Type : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll'.
At D:\Users\username\Documents\sharepoint-uploader\Invoke-RestSPO.ps1:1 char:1`.

Comment: Just an FYI, I had to replace the first two lines in `Invoke-RestSPO.ps1` with `Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"`. Seems like `-` character is different in the one you referred.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the snapin is to load the module directly in PowerShell.

```
& ' C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\CONFIG\POWERSHELL\Registration\\sharepoint.ps1 '
```

Comment: ....and the syntax to load the module would be?  Putting single quotes around the path to it ain't it...

Comment: The ampersand "&" symbol means 'execute what follows'. You could also CD to that path on a SharePoint Server and execute the sharepoint.ps1 directly.

Comment: I get `The term 'sharepoint.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1 + sharepoint.ps1 +~~~~~~ +CategoryInfo: ObjectNotFound: (sharepoint.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException +FullyQualifiedErrorId: CommandNotFoundException Suggestion [3,General]: The command sharepoint.ps1 was not found, but does exist in the current location. Windows PowerShell does not load commands from the current location by default.`

Comment: `If you trust this command, instead type: ".\sharepoint.ps1". See "get-help about_Command_Precedence" for more details.` So I tried `.\sharepoint.ps1` instead and got `Add-PsSnapin : No snap-ins have been registered for Window PowerShell version 5.` - which of course is the very thing I've been trying to workaround. Same error if I use the "&" technique. Note that I'm attempting this on another computer than the SharePoint server, just like the OP, and just copied `sharepoint.ps1` to it. Maybe there's other things it needs from the server?

Answer (score 1):

The is no need to open a PSSession with the server, you can just use the CSOM service as @vadim says (another answer in this thread), in order to work with lists or Sharepoint sites data. Here is a very good guide which details the first steps: https://www.itunity.com/article/connecting-spo-csom-api-powershell-1038

Comment: As I understand it, the PowerShell snap-in has more capabilities than the CSOM. (It's more comparable to the SSOM.)

Comment: that's correct @jpaugh

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged, and this one is now broken.  Saying "Use the CSOM service" is incredibly vague.  Summarize what other pages say so answers here don't become useless.

Comment: It's a good idea to copy across the relevant points when posting answers. That website currently throws a 404